# When I call a function I get: Process returned -1073741819

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am writing a program to print a fee invoice of a student. When I call my function getPrefix() my program essentially crashes and says Process returned -1073741819; the program compiles and everything.

The problem is occuring in my deleteCourse() function. I call the function getPrefix() to print out the name associated with the specific crn and the program crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LOAD 12
#define creditHour 120.25

// prototype functions above main
void printMenu();
void addCourse(int [], int crnValid[]);
void courseList ();
int deleteCourse (int [], int crnValid[]);
char* getPrefix (int);
void  printInvoice (int [], int);

int main()
{ // start main

    int studentId ;
    int option = 1;
    int crn[MAX_LOAD] = {0}; // used to keep track of courses being taken
    int crnValid[MAX_LOAD] = {4587,4599,8997,9696,7895,9658,4287,9599,8927,7696,7890,9008} ; // used to check if crns are valid

    printf("Welcome! Enter the student's ID number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &studentId);

    while (option != 0){
    printMenu();
    scanf("%d", &option);

    switch(option){
    case 1:
        addCourse (crn, crnValid);
        break;
    case 2:
        deleteCourse (crn, crnValid);
        break;
    case 3:
        printInvoice (crn, studentId) ;
        break;
    case 0:
        break;
    default:
        printf("Please enter a valid option: \n");
    } ;
}

return 0;
} // end main
// define functions below main
 // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void printMenu(){
printf("\n---------------------------------\n") ;
printf("Choose from the following options:\n");
printf("1- Add a course for the student\n");
printf("2- Drop a course for the student\n");
printf("3- Print the fee invoice\n");
printf("0- Exit program\n");
printf("---------------------------------\n") ;
printf("Enter your selection: ");
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void addCourse(int crn[], int crnValid[]){
    char choice ;
    printf("Would you like to print the list of courses? (y/n)");
    scanf(" %c", &choice) ;

    if (choice == 'y'){
    courseList();
    }

    int i; // loop incrementer
    int success = 0;
    int valid;

    for (i = 1; i < MAX_LOAD; i++){

        if (crn[i] == 0){
        printf("Enter the course number to add: ");
        scanf("%d", &crn[i]);
        success = 1; // success = 1 when course has not been taken
        break ;
        }
        }

    if (success == 0){
        printf("Course can't be added, you have attained the max number of courses!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Course added, you have added course %d\n", crn[i]) ;
    }

}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void courseList ()
{
    printf("CRN\tCOURSE\t\tCREDIT HOURS\n");
    printf("4587\tMAT 236\t\t4\n");
    printf("4599\tCOP 220\t\t3\n");
    printf("8997\tGOL 124\t\t1\n");
    printf("9696\tCOP 100\t\t3\n");
    printf("7895\tMNT 125\t\t2\n");
    printf("9658\tOPT 120\t\t3\n");
    printf("4287\tMAT 836\t\t4\n");
    printf("9599\tCOP 220\t\t3\n");
    printf("8927\tGOM 124\t\t3\n");
    printf("7696\tCOT 100\t\t4\n");
    printf("7890\tMOT 125\t\t3\n");
    printf("9008\tOPT 520\t\t5\n");
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int deleteCourse(int crn[], int crnValid[])
{
    int i;
    int success = 0;
    int crnToDelete;

    printf("Enter the course number to delete: ");
    scanf("%d", &crnToDelete);

    char prefix[20]  ;

    for (i=1; i < MAX_LOAD; i++){
    if ( crn[i] == crnToDelete )
    {
        crn[i] = 0;  // deletes course from array crn
        success = 1;
        break;
    }
    }

if (success == 0){
    printf("The student isn't taking %d/%s", crnToDelete, getPrefix(crnToDelete)) ;
}
else {
    printf("Course deleted!\n");
}

return crnToDelete ;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

char* getPrefix (int crnToDelete){
    switch(crnToDelete){
    case 4587:
        return "MAT 236";
    case 4599:
        return "COP 220";
    case 8997:
        return "GOL 124";
    case 9696:
        return "COP 100";
    case 4580:
        return "MAT 230";
    case 4581:
        return "MAT 231";
    case 4582:
        return "MAT 232";
    case 4583:
        return "MAT 233";
    case 3587:
        return "MAT 256";
    case 4519:
        return "COP 420";
    case 6997:
        return "GOL 127";
    case 9494:
        return "COP 101";
    }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void printInvoice (int crn [], int studentId)
{
   printf("\n\tVALENCIA COMMUNITY COLLEGE\n");
   printf("\tORLANDO FL 10101\n");
   printf("\t----------------------------\n");
   printf("\n\tFee Invoice Prepared for Student V%d\n", studentId);
   printf("\n\t1 Credit Hour = $ 120.25\n");
   printf("\n\tCRN\tCR_PREFIX\tCR_HOURS");

   int i;
   for (i=1; i < MAX_LOAD; i++)
   {
       if (crn[i] != 0){ // if a course is in spot i, print course
        printf("\n\t%d\n", crn[i]) ;
       }
   }

   printf("\n\t\tHealth and Id fees:\t  $ 35.00");
   printf("\n\t-----------------------------------------");
   printf("\n\t\tTotal Payments:") ;

}
```

Comment: `getPrefix()` doesn't have a return value set for values not listed in the `switch`, and you don't check whether your `scanf()` successfully reads `crnToDelete`.  If you enter an unlisted course number, or the `scanf()` fails (maybe due to non-numeric input left in the input stream before the number?), you'll have problems.  Your compiler probably would've warned you about `getPrefix()` missing a return value.

Comment: I am first checking if the switch in getPrefix() is working by entering a known course number, one that is listed in the switch. I am trying to get this to work first before going back in and adding more stuff. Why would it not work with a known course?

Comment: If `scanf()` didn't read the number successfully, `crnToDelete` would remain uninitialised, so you'd likely pass an unknown course number.  The scan might fail if there is still data in the stream (such as a left-over line ending) that isn't interpreted as part of a number.  You should check the return from `scanf()` to make sure it succeeds, and handle unknown values in `getPrefix()` (at least add a `default` case to the switch).  Also, try adding a space to the start of your `scanf()` format strings to read off whitespace left in the stream before scanning the number.